# Gradle build failed in Android Studio when adding Google analytics

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, build.gradle

Hello I am new to Android Studio and working on adding Google analtics in my project I am reffering a sample project from Google analytics official site, the demo working fine, but when I am adding code from my project, it says below error,

**error**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Stush:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
  You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
  However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

this is my gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            name 'maven.aviary.com'
            url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}



apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.stush"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        name 'maven.aviary.com'
        url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

    compile files('picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('ion-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    // compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
    compile files('androidasync-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/fluent-hc-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpclient-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpclient-cache-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/http_client/httpmime-4.3.2.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    dexOptions {
    }
}
```

Please help me to save me.Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error, you have included more than one library with the `com.google.android.gms` package name. Probably its
`compile project(':google-play-services_libs')`
and
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`

You should remove one of these.

Comment: but when i am removing compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0`,all code relates to google analytics comes with error..:(

Comment: @sulphuricAcid Do you need the local google-play-services_libs?